# MATLAB Polygon Self Intersection - Delete Zero Volume Parts

Tags: matlab, polygon

I have a MATLAB polygon (below) which self intersects to make the zero volume part (which I will call a sliver) in the image (also below).

I am having a lot of trouble finding and removing the zero volume sliver.

Hope anyone can help. Thanks.

IMAGE:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4yOr.jpg)

Polygon:

newBoundary =

```
       1           1
       1         216
       8         221
      25         239
      46         255
      60         269
      70         282
      81         296
      92         313
     113         323
     127         326
     145         336
     163         349
     170         368
     174         374
     192         388
     209         400
     229         416
     236         433
     252         450
     266         470
     268         488
     274         504
     284         523
     274         518
     249         513
     246         532
     246         538
     224         527
     216         541
     206         554
     205         573
     192         589
     185         590
     169         609
     148         620
     154         641
     170         646
     172         660
     165         683
     154         673
     140         654
     130         648
     116         656
     105         660
      92         679
      82         700
      69         719
      90         730
      77         751
      87         770
      66         763
      48         774
      37         791
      28         804
      18         804
       9         817
       1         834
       1         838
       1        1049
     131        1049
     141        1044
     164        1029
     181        1014
     193        1004
     208         995
     221         979
     239         979
     239         962
     253         951
     270         940
     290         926
     299         908
     317         899
     332         879
     353         869
     364         857
     379         841
     376         856
     386         870
     383         889
     380         913
     382         933
     383         958
     378         975
     379         993
     378        1016
     374        1029
     367        1040
     366        1049
     616        1049
     615        1049
     610        1037
     615        1016
     612         993
     618         978
     612         953
     609         936
     606         913
     608         894
     609         874
     606         854
     622         839
     633         853
     651         869
     670         883
     690         900
     706         916
     721         934
     740         951
     747         971
     765         978
     785         992
     795        1007
     816        1015
     831        1028
     848        1049
    1049        1049
    1049         781
    1027         784
    1003         780
     997         798
     974         812
     973         796
     964         780
     947         765
     930         773
     922         760
     926         736
     917         722
     898         713
     879         719
     883         704
     886         679
     873         663
     853         670
     847         649
     841         627
     839         607
     835         621
     814         631
     794         620
     778         604
     761         588
     744         601
     729         592
     716         577
     705         556
     698         537
     689         517
     698         502
     711         486
     726         486
     730         463
     743         446
     760         439
     764         420
     784         404
     802         388
     816         373
     837         366
     846         344
     866         337
     881         324
     901         314
     912         299
     926         283
     946         272
     951         253
     970         242
     977         225
     998         223
    1006         207
    1025         192
    1049         186
    1049           1
     789           1
     792           6
     778          20
     774          37
     762          49
     753          70
     736          79
     715          90
     695         100
     672          91
     668         109
     663         131
     668         153
     651         156
     657         168
     648         170
     633         153
     612         150
     613         127
     610         114
     613          97
     615          74
     613          54
     612          36
     613          21
     620           1
     380           1
     379           9
     377          34
     371          56
     379          78
     387          98
     379         117
     376         136
     384         151
     372         156
     350         164
     332         174
     318         168
     327         150
     309         139
     299         129
     281         127
     290         108
     275         107
     261          90
     236          76
     235          60
     219          52
     206          35
     187          22
     168           4
     156           1
       1           1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zero volume slivers may occur when there are three or more consecutive points aligned. In this particular case those were:

```
366        1049
616        1049
615        1049
```

since they fall on the same horizontal line.

If you want to automate this, you should check every group of three consecutive points to see if they fall on the same line. If they do, you need to discard the one in the middle, according to appearance order.

In this particular case, the one in the middle is:

```
616        1049
```

Comment: Many thanks, this IS a good answer... but I need a code (not manual)  implementation